# How do you handle this kind of probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices

*What is the probability of selecting a singular matrix from $\Bbb{R}^{3\times 3}$?*

I calculated it to be zero based on their being approximately $9$ degrees of freedom to choose entries of $A$ such that $\det(A) \neq 0$, and $9$ degrees of freedom in choosing any $A \in \Bbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, and took $9/9 = 1$ as the probability of selecting a non-singular.  However I approximated the first number in the sense that if a variable (degree of freedom) could be chosen from $\Bbb{R} - \{0\}$ then it counts as $1$ full degree of freedom the same as a choice from $\Bbb{R}$ untouched.  So this obviously doesn't work??

Or does it work since singular matrices are extremely rare but we only look at matrices for relatively small (human-sized) values?  I can't explain it.  How would you go about calculating this type of probability?  Thanks.

Comment: This is missing the crucial information of how you select a $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: Yeah, I know, how do you randomely select an element from $\Bbb{R}$???  It's impossible!!!!!

Comment: If you think it's impossible to randomly select a real number then why are you asking a question about randomly selecting 9 of them?  (By which I mean, it would be a good idea to start by thinking about just the real numbers)

Comment: @mathematician I didn't think of that til after Did posted.

Comment: Hence "Yeah, I know"?

Comment: The relevant modification of the setting of your question is well known: to draw the entries of the matrix according to a genuine probability measure (most notably, normal or Bernoulli).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have noted, your question is difficult to answer because we don't know how to choose a random real number.  In the language of probability theory, the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, and probability studies finite measure spaces (so $\mathbb{R}$ under Lebesgue measure is excluded).

However, we can still ask the following measure-theoretic question:

> In the infinite measure space $M_3(\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}^9$, what is the measure of the set of singular matrices?

The answer to this question is indeed $0$, which validates your intuition that "most" matrices are invertible.  The singular matrices have measure $0$ because they are a hypersurface, that is, they are defined by the zero set of a single polynomial equation (the determinant).  In general, proper Zariski closed sets have measure $0$.

Edit: As requested by Rookatu's comment, here is a bit more, although I'm not sure if you have any background in Real Analysis, so this may not be helpful to you at the moment.

Suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^9$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $m$.  This means that $m(A)=0$ implies $\mu(A)=0$ for all measurable sets $A$.  This is equivalent to the existence of some Lebesgue integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}^9\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\mu(A)=\int_Af\;dm$$

for all measurable $A$.  This function $f$ is called the density of $\mu$, and in our case, it is a probability density function, that is, its integral over all of $\mathbb{R}^9$ is $1$.

Now, as noted above, if $A$ is the set of singular matrices in $\mathbb{R}^9$, then $m(A)=0$, so by absolute continuity, we also have $\mu(A)=0$.  All of this shows that if you describe your process of picking a matrix at random using a probability density function $f:\mathbb{R}^9\to\mathbb{R}$, no matter which $f$ you choose, the answer to your problem is the same: the probability that a random matrix is singular is $0$.

Comment: "probability studies finite measure spaces (so $\mathbb{R}$ is excluded)" Quite untrue.

Comment: @Did: Can you explain?  I understand that a probability space is a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ with $\mu(X)=1$.

Comment: Which does not exclude $X=\mathbb R$ at all. Of course, if $\mathbb R$ is equipped with the Lebesgue measure, then the total mass is infinite. (Since you modified your answer to this effect after my comment was posted, you are aware that this was the problem with your original answer and I am not sure to understand your "Can you explain?" comment.)

Comment: By the way, the relevant modification of the OP's question is not, as you suggest, to drop the finiteness of the measure but to draw the entries of the matrix according to a genuine probability measure (most notably, normal or Bernoulli).

Comment: @Jared It might be a good idea to add to your post a comment about what this means if you are randomly selecting matrices according to a distribution which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^9$, i.e. one with a density. That might make the connection to the question even stronger. Thanks!

Comment: @Rookatu: Thanks for the suggestion (note the edit).  It has been years since I've given any serious thought to Real Analysis.

Comment: How can the probability be zero if there's a chance that the first matrix is singular???  Other than that, great lecture.  I understood some of it :)

Comment: @Jared No problem, nice edit!

Comment: @EnjoysMath: Try reading about ["almost sure vs. sure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#.22Almost_sure.22_versus_.22sure.22), especially the example given concerning the dart board.  This will help explain what mathematicians mean by an event occuring with zero probability.